# How to set flaskform field value by javascript

Tags: javascript, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a JavaScript calender that when a user clicks on a date, the date is submitted together with other fields when the User submits the FlaskForm for validation.

I've managed to obtain the date dynamically, but when I set the date as the FlaskForm field value, the form validates but the date field comes out empty.

How can I properly submit the dynamic date data to FlaskForm using JavaScript?

#### Python

```py
if createslot_form.validate_on_submit():
  slot = Slot(
    start_time=str(createslot_form.start_time.data), 
    end_time=str(createslot_form.end_time.data),
    quantity=int(createslot_form.quantity.data), 
    date=str(createslot_form.date.data),
    room_id=int(room_id)
  )
  db.session.add(slot)
  db.session.commit()
  print('slot has been added')
  return redirect(url_for('edit_room', room_id=room_id))
return render_template('room.html', room=room, createslot_form=createslot_form, created_slots_json=created_slots_json, room_link=str(room_link))
```

#### Javascript

```js
function new_event(event) {
  if ($(".active-date").length != 0) {
    var day = $(".active-date")[0].innerText;
    var month = $(".active-month")[0].innerText;
    var year = $(".year")[0].innerText;
    var click_date = day + ' ' + month + ' ' + year;
    console.log($(".form-control")[0]);
    
    $(".form-control")[0].value = click_date;
    $(".form-control")[0].placeholder = click_date;
  }
}
```

Comment: When you look at the date field in the browser's dev tools, do you see the value changing there? When you submit the form, do you see the value attached to the correct field in the request body? Please update your post with more context — the definition of createslot_form and the HTML, if possible.

Comment: Agree with Karl, without HTML and more context it's hard to say where the problem. One of the possible issue is that you have type=date for date input, so in this case you should set date value in the format `YYYY-MM-DD `, or use `valueAsDate` attribute to set as Date object.